# Resultado indefinido post json data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsonobject

Tengo el siguiente codigo

**html**

```
<form>
<input type="hidden" id="tipoCentro" name="tipoCentro" value="CM">
<input type="text" id="filtroCentro" name="filtroCentro" placeholder="Buscar">

<ul class="centroSalud">
 </ul>
</form>
```

**Js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#filtroCentro").keyup(function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    //var fcentro = $('#filtroCentro').val();
    var tcentro = $('#tipoCentro').val();

    if(search != ""){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://myurl.com/api/Buscar',
            type: 'post',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                Nombre: search,Tipo: tcentro
    }),
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

            success:function(response){

                var len = response.length;
                $(".centroSalud").empty();
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var id = response[i]['Tipo'];
                    var fname = response[i]['Nombre'];

                    $(".centroSalud").append("<li value='"+id+"'>"+fname+"</li>");                   
                }

            }
        });
    }

});

});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Al realizar una busqueda con el evento onkeyup, el resultado que me arroja es undefined , alguna idea de que puedo estar haciendo mal

Gracias

Comment: Amigo, el undefined es porque no encuentra ese valor y simplemente no tiene como mostrarlo. Estas iterando pero en esa iteracion no encuentra encuentra la Clave Nombre y te mostrara Undefined.

Comment: Para ver que recibes, puedes hacer un console.log(response) y ver como esta construido el json que recibes.